# Create a new record for every user in a database based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a `user` table, after a new requirement I had to create a new table called `social_media` and from now on every new user will be created with a `social_media_id` column that holds a reference to their social media.

```
 +===================+ +===================+
 |   user            | |   social_media    |
 +===================+ +===================+
 |PK id              | |PK id              |
 |FK social_media_id | |   instagram       |
 |   first_name      | |   facebook        |
 |   last_name       | |   twitter         |
 |   email           | +===================+
 +===================+
```

I want to update my database so that every user that didn't had a social media reference before gets one (even if the values inside are null), so they can update them if they wish, is there something I can do to make a new `social_media` record for every user that doesn't have one, and add the correct `social_media_id` foreign key for that `user`?

Comment: youre data structure seems backwards. social_media should have a column for userID and not the other way around. Realistically, the social_media table is a many to one relationship with users. To even  further that point, the social_media table should not have multiple columns for SM entities - more so a record per entity per user.  This solution becomes infinitely easier when your normalize correctly

Comment: @DougCoats Now that you mention it, you're right, it makes more sense to have the id on the social_media table and a column `name` that represents what type of social media is, I wanted it to be all on the `user` table to make it easier to update, however, how would you create the new records for all users that don't have it already?

Comment: Maybe you should have it like this : `User (PK id, first_name, last_name, email)`, `social_media (pk id, social_media_name)`, and another table for `user_social_media (pk id, fk user_id, fk social_media_id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok @Jorche, this is too long to be a comment, but I do want to help.

First off, this is *probably* what youre data structure should look like:

[image]

Second, to be able to tell you how you enter these records is very difficult for me at this moment because I have absolutely ZERO requirements or any other business logic that would help me to help you on how to pinpoint the best approach to doing so. Odds are, you would have to work hand in hand with application developers, or ETL developers (that might even be you though) to figure out what that approach is. Maybe its a stored procedure that gets called, maybe its a trigger set up, hard to say for sure without additional context, ya know?

All we know at this point is that users exist and sometimes they have relational data related to social media entities. Your job is literally to understand that process flow and make the appropriate decisions on how to log that data in a way that makes sense from both an operational perspective and a database design perspective.

Hate to say it hombre, but the questions you have now are all entirely dependent on details you haven't provided.

Comment: Might be fair to mention - the naming conventions in my screen shot are garbage. Also, i used access's relational designer, sue me - its quick and easy for SO q&a

Comment: Hey @Doug, I really appreciate the response. I'm thinking about changing to the new data structure, since we also want to have very specific types of social media, beyond that I'm going to do more research into stored procedures which I'm thinking could be the way to create the records that we need